# Ubuntu Server 20.04 on Dell Precision T5500, Displayport recognized but not showing video

Tags: drivers, graphics

I'm not a complete beginner to Linux but I'm pretty inexperienced. I recently had a Thinkserver TS140 die on me so I replaced it with a cheap used Dell T5500.

So far I'm perfectly happy with the replacement, except for one issue I can't solve. On Debian, Ubuntu, and Ubuntu server the installation process runs fine, but afterwards when booting up to the full installation I get power to my monitor, as if it's recognizing a signal, but then I just continually get a message that the monitor will soon enter sleep mode (every 10-15 seconds) and nothing ever displays. I was able to install Fedora workstation and run it just fine, so I assume it has something to do with Debian's compatibility with the hardware. The troublesome GPU is an AMD FirePro 3D, I'm unsure of the exact model number.

Things I have tried:

- running `sudo apt-get update` to update packages
- Updating mesa drivers
- Using xrandr commands, all of which are met with "can't open display"
- Editing the `modprobe.d` conf files for radeon and amdgpu. I couldn't find them there and I wasn't sure if I needed to create the .conf files and then add in the lines to enable amdgpu and disable radeon. This is the solution I was on before I had to leave for work today. The same person suggested possibly editing Grub, but I wasn't confident about that.

I apologize for poor formatting and a lack of more comprehensive info, I can give any info needed once I am back home, just looking to see if anyone has had similar issues with this particular card before.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Let us know how it works when you add the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`

Comment: No change, I've temporarily swapped to an old nvidia PNY card just to get some setup done.

However, I did try some other steps in the meantime. I was unable to change `radeon` to `amdgpu` for the display module, even after blacklisting radeon and disabling it in grub. I also tried both the amdgpu and amdgpu-pro drivers, with opencl, and no luck.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU) can help you.

Comment: Sadly, those are actually the exact steps I followed. I eventually learned that I had to downgrade the linux kernel version to support the driver required to run the Firepro v4800, however by that point I had already gotten a cheap alternative card

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resolution of the problem in this question. Sorry that we could find no way to use that AMD card.